# iOS esri sdk - Multiple Popups using AGSPopupsContainerViewController

Tags: ios, arcgis, esri

I am using AGSPopupsContainerViewController to display multiple popups when touching on mapView we fetch more than one AGSGraphics.
Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *popups =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
AGSPopupInfo *popupinfo;

for (AGSGraphic *g in Graphics ) {
   popupinfo =[AGSPopupInfo popupInfoForGraphic:g] ;
   AGSPopup* popup = [AGSPopup popupWithGraphic:g popupInfo:popupinfo];
   popup.allowEditGeometry = false;
   [popups addObject:popup];

}

if (!popupVC) {
    self.popupVC = [[AGSPopupsContainerViewController alloc] initWithPopups:popups     
    usingNavigationControllerStack:false];
}else{
    [self.popupVC showAdditionalPopups:popups];

}

self.popupVC.delegate = self;

self.popupVC.doneButton = self.customActionButton;
self.popupVC.style = AGSPopupsContainerStyleCustomColor;
self.popupVC.barItemTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.popupVC.pagingStyle = AGSPopupsContainerPagingStyleToolbar;

// Animate by flipping horizontally
self.popupVC.modalTransitionStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

// If iPad, use a modal presentation style
if([[AGSDevice currentDevice] isIPad])
    self.popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentViewController:self.popupVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

All works fine, I have the right number of pupups, the problem is that using the arrows in the toolbar I can only see the first and the last ones. Why? I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrows are doing what they are supposed to do - using them will show you the first and the last popup. Swipe to the left (or right) and you'll see the rest of the popups.

Comment: I've figured it out already. However it's not very clear from the icons.Thanks!